# Unable to receive form data from Frontend using React/Django

Tags: python, django, reactjs, postman, form-data

I have been working on Pinterest-like app where users can upload pins along with a picture. After crafting "FileView", which is the API that uploads a received file onto S3 and provide the Frontend with the resulting URL for the picture, I have tested with Postman successfully. Below are my views.py code snippet and the screenshot of Postman request.

views.py

```
class FileView(View):
    s3_client = boto3.client(
        's3',
        aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    )

    @login_required
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):

        user        = kwargs['user']
        user_id     = kwargs['user_id']
        name        = request.POST.get('title')
        paragraph1  = request.POST.get('text', None)
        board       = request.POST.get('board', 1)
        board       = Board.objects.get(id=board)
        print(request.FILES)
        if request.FILES == None:
            return JsonResponse({"message": "REQUEST FILES IS EMPTY"}, status=406)
        file        = request.FILES['filename']

        self.s3_client.upload_fileobj(
            file,
            "pinterrorist",
            file.name,
            ExtraArgs={
                "ContentType": file.content_type
            }
        )

        image_url       = S3URL+file.name
        image_url       = image_url.replace(" ", "+")
        new_pin         = Pin.objects.create(
            image_url   = image_url,
            name        = name,
            paragraph1  = paragraph1,
            board       = board
        )
        new_pin.user.add(user)

        new_pin = model_to_dict(new_pin, fields=["image_url", "name", "paragraph1", "board"])

        return JsonResponse({"new_pin": new_pin})
```

[image: POSTMAN screenshot]

However, when I try to work it out with the frontend, the request does not go through the views.py. It goes through the decorator, which means there is nothing wrong with the header's authorization token. I searched online to find ways to fix this but one of them mentioned I need to get rid of headers but I cannot do so because the request MUST contain headers with an authorization token.

Below is the code my co-worker crafted using REACT.

```
const savePins = () => {
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("filename", uploadedfile);
    fd.append("title", title);
    fd.append("text", imgDes);
    fetch("http://10.58.0.207:8000/pin-builder", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        // "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
        "Content-Type":
          "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryIn312MOjBWdkffIM",
        Authorization:
          "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6IjIifQ.kg_TKT_XrRsqMRGUSAac5Uonq3STzSLDlt9d5ZbRzFw",
      },
      body: fd,
    }).then(function (res) {
      if (res.ok) {
        alert("Perfect");
        console.log(res);
      } else {
        alert("Oops");
        console.log(res);
      }
    });}
```

When she sends the request, I tried to figure out the part where it sends back the error. I used pdb to found the part:

```
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'filename'
> /Users/woohyunan/projects/Wecode/pinterrorist-backend/pin/views.py(90)post()
-> file        = request.FILES['filename']
```

Is there something wrong with either the frontend(react) or backend(django) code? I don't know anything about REACT programming but I would like to know how to fix this so that I can keep working on this project with the front-end engineers.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Have you tried removing just the "Content-Type" header but leaving the "Authorization" header?

Comment: Yes, we have tried it but didn't work.

Comment: What is `uploadedfile`? Is it definitely a file object? Can you share the code that defines this variable

Comment: `const fileChangeHandler = (e) => {
    const files = e.target.files;
    console.log(files);
    setUploadedfile(files);
  };`

Comment: `<Uploader
                    id="ImageUploader"
                    onChange={fileChangeHandler}
                    type="file"
                    accept="image/bmp,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png,image/tiff,image/webp"
                  ></Uploader>`

Comment: Does `console.log(files)` log an array? If it does you need to use `setUploadedfile(files[0])`

Comment: Will try right now!

Comment: It's working!!!! Thanks a lot